# What is the generic signature of a method that returns an instance of a given subclass?

Tags: java, generics

Basically I want to create a method that has a signature like the following:

```
public <T> T getShellTab(Class<T extends ShellTab> shellTabClass)
```

but this isn't valid Java.
I want to be able to pass a class that is a subclass of `ShellTab` and have an instance of that class returned.

```
public <T> T getShellTab(Class<T> shellTabClass)
```

works fine, but I would like to force `shellTabClass` to be a subclass of `ShellTab`.

Any ideas on how to pull this off?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put the constraint in the initial generic parameter, like this:

```
public <T extends ShellTab> T getShellTab(Class<T> shellTabClass)
```

Note that you can have constraints on the generic type parameters of the method parameters (for instance, [Tom Hawtin - tackline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline) suggests making `shellTabClass` into a `Class<? extends T>`, although I don't think it makes a difference in this case).
But you can't constrain a type that has already been declared.

Comment: Probably public <T extends ShellTab> T getShellTab(Class<? extends T> shellTabClass).

Comment: Does that buy anything over what I posted? T could be any subclass of ShellTab anyway, right?

Comment: D'Oh! Its so simple now! Awesome, that works great thank you.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
public <T extends ShellTab> T getShellTab(Class<T> shellTabClass)
```